# How do I disable Google AMP in search results on iOS?

Tags: google-search, mobile, iphone, google-amp

When I search Google on an iPhone, website links are often replaced with slimmed-down AMP versions. Getting to the original webpage with full-functionality requires opening an extra page.

How do I disable Google AMP pages when searching on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 15, you can use the Safari extension [Amplosion](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1585734696) to automatically redirect away from AMP links.